# Download a list of files with wget using wildcards

Tags: bash, downloads, wget, wildcards

I have a list of files like:

```
test.com/image01.png
test.com/image02.png
test.com/image03.png
...
test.com/image50.png
```

and want to download them all. One way is to write all names in a file and then:

```
$ wget -i url.txt
```

But for 50 links (at least), it's a little to long to write all in a file (even by copy and pasting, I have to edit one line 49 times.)

I tested something like:

```
$ wget test.com/image[01-50].png
Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.
--2019-09-22 01:45:43--  test.com/image[01-50].png
Resolving test.com (test.com)... 12.12.12.12
Connecting to test.com (test.com)|12.12.12.12|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-09-22 01:45:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

How can I use wildcards in `wget`? Should I use any switches?

Comment: Try brace expansion: `wget test.com/image{01..50}.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [John1024](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175755/download-a-list-of-files-with-wget-using-wildcards?noredirect=1#comment1962740_1175755), brace expansion is the solution:

```
$ wget test.com/image{01..50}.png
```

Answer (score 0):

for the list of files for a web page for Firefox there is a Firefox extension Linkgopher  that will give you a page with links, then you can save that to a text file. It accepts a filter.
https://sites.google.com/site/linkgopher/

as you know wget can take a text file as input

this is mine, <> means your input or delete that parameter, edit: those braces didnt show up, so if there is no paramater given, put one in or delete it.

wget --input-file= --show-progress --limit-rate=200K --random-wait --no-directories --continue --rejected-log=  --output-file= --directory-prefix= --user= --password=